# Obtaining token from Github App for accessing all repos in organization

Tags: github, trufflehog

I need to perform an organizational scan for secrets using trufflehog in all private repos within the Github organization. I created a Github App, and saved the App ID and the Private Key as secrets. Github APP has been granted all possible permissions. I know that whose should be as restricted as possible, but I did it because I did not know what I am doing wrong. I use actions/create-github-app-token@v1 action for token generation.

```
  - name: Generate a token
    id: generate-token
    uses: actions/create-github-app-token@v1
    with:
      app-id: ${{ secrets.APP_ID }}
      private-key: ${{ secrets.APP_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      owner: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
```

When the scan is running, I keep getting the following error:

```
{"level":"error","ts":"2024-02-05T23:49:24Z","logger":"trufflehog","msg":"engine failed to finish execution","error":"fatal: error getting user: GET https://api.github.com/user: 403 Resource not accessible by integration []"}
```

Any ideas?